# How to use AddHandler in httpd 2.4 for php-fpm version change

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, php-fpm, httpd, fastcgi

I have the following setup for httpd 2.2 (CentOS 6) with `mod_fastcgi` and `php-fpm`:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
Action application/x-httpd-php71 /php71-fcgi
Alias /php71-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php71-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php71-fcgi -socket /var/run/php71.sock -pass-header Authorization

Action application/x-httpd-php72 /php72-fcgi
Alias /php72-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php72-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php72-fcgi -socket /var/run/php72.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But in httpd 2.4 (CentOS 7) there is `mod_proxy_fcgi` and since `mod_fastcgi` is not available I don't have `FastCgiExternalServer` I'm trying something like this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
Action application/x-httpd-php70 /php70-fpm virtual
Alias /php70-fpm /php70-fpm
ProxyPassMatch "/php70-fpm" "unix:/var/run/php70.sock|fcgi://localhost"

Action application/x-httpd-php72 /php72-fpm virtual
Alias /php72-fpm /usr/local/php-fpm/php72-fpm
ProxyPass "/usr/local/php-fpm/php72-fpm" 
"unix:/var/run/php72.sock|fcgi://localhost"

<Directory /usr/local/php-fpm>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I know it's wrong (and not working...) but for the moment I'm not able to find (if there is one) a way to keep using `AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpXX .php` in `.htaccess` for version change with CentOS7/Apache 2.4. I know I could use:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/var/run/php70.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

but I'm looking for a way to keep my .htaccess the same.

Comment: no, you must use the sethandler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit I found out that there is "Define" directive that could be used:

I've added in fcgi.conf (included in httpd.conf) the following:

```
Define php70 "proxy:unix:/var/run/php70.sock|fcgi://localhost"
```

And after that used the defined "php70" for a `AddHandler` in `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler ${php70} .php
```

That's the closest thing I've managed to find. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: So the point of the question was to keep using the directive "AddHandler", not the directive and parameters as it was before. I sincerily do not understand the motives.

Comment: The motives are that most of us work with users, and it's easier for the user to get used to this: `AddHandler ${application/x-httpd-phpXX} .php` (or something similar) than the `SetHandler` method